# *Where* to give credit for Creative Commons licensed work?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

[These](http://mollykleinman.com/2008/08/15/cc-howto-1-how-to-attribute-a-creative-commons-licensed-work/) [articles](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/best_practices_for_attribution) explains *how* to give credit for [CC-licensed](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) work, but I can't information on *where* to give credit.

Suppose I want to use [an icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1433396/black_background_diagram_finance_pie_chart_presentation_report_icon#size=128) on my commercial website -- I can't exactly credit the author next to every 16x16 icon I use throughout the site. Is it fair/legal to have a sort of licenses/credit page linked in the footer of my page, that simply lists out every licensed thing that I use?

If I do, do I need to render the icon on that page too so that people know immediately know to what I am referring, or can I just link back to the source pages?

Comment: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/best_practices_for_attribution

Comment: @RobertHarvey I linked that specific article in my question. Can you point out where it answers my question?

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/27395.  Also, note that iconfinder itself also links to https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/best_practices_for_attribution, so maybe you're missing something.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Clearly I am. That article gives examples of attribution. As in, what text/links should I include to properly attribute the author. That's great, I get that. But I still can't find anywhere that says whether or not a `<!-- comment -->` in my HTML is acceptable, or if I need a "Credits" page, or if I can bury it 20 links deep on my website, or what.

Answer (score 2):

You should be reasonable when giving credits properly, so the copyright notice should be visible and easy to find, preferably in the same page that the copyrighted resource was used (but you can also link to a page that contains all the required information), in a fashion that *is both visible and unambigous to humans and computers*.

> You may satisfy the conditions in Section 3(a)(1) in any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context in which You Share the Licensed Material. (From the CC 4.0 legal code)

To achieve this goal you should use RDFa for the metadata and clearly state that the work is licensed, see [Marking Works Technical](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Marking_Works_Technical#Web).
For instance there's an icon in your main page that you are displaying using

```
<img src="bar.jpg">
```

When adding the licence information in your footer/credits page you should put some qualifiers in it e.g.

```
Icon licensed under <a about="/bar.jpg" rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LICENSE_INFORMATION">a Creative Commons License</a>
```

(This example is adapted from the CC wiki, for more examples go to the [RDFa Primer](https://www.w3.org/2006/07/SWD/RDFa/primer/))

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fair/legal to have a sort of licenses/credit page linked in the footer of my page, that simply lists out every licensed thing that I use?

Yes, I think so. It is very common for a copyright notice to be included at the bottom of every page of a given site. If the page contains small icons that you don't own the copyright to, this is the best place to note it. If there are many such, with many distinct attributions, then you can indicate as much, and provide a link to the details, as you suggest.

By the way, it's better to err on the side of attribution that is *too* visible than attribution that is not visible *enough*. When you're adding a copyright notice, it may seem glaringly unsubtle to you (because you're focusing on it), so you might feel tempted to make it ridiculously tiny and/or ridiculously faint. Resist that temptation. It's OK (and common) for it to be somewhat smaller and optionally fainter than the regular page font, but it should still be easy to read. Since it's in the footer, and it's very obvious what it is, people who aren't interested in it will ignore it (without even noticing that they're ignoring it).

> If I do, do I need to render the icon on that page too so that people know immediately know to what I am referring, or can I just link back to the source pages?

If the icon has a title, then technically that's all that's needed to identify it (and you have to provide the title anyway as part of the attribution requirement); but rendering the icon itself sounds like a good idea, IMHO.